# StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation warning on pre launched .aab release

Tags: flutter, view, google-play, androidx, android-app-bundle

I have been struggling with this issue but stil no answer I have found by googling. **After applying sslcommerz payment gateway getting the warning**. Though it seems to be a related question but no proper solution is available on github or stackoverflow. Here I attached warning log.

Note : both .aab and .apk file are doing well before play store upload

Stacktrace 1:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/util/LongArray;->get(I)J
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:475)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:429)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:70)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.<init>(AccessibilityBridge.java:352)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(FlutterView.java:912)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:303)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:520)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:414)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Stacktrace 2:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->getSourceNodeId()J
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:446)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:429)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:70)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.<init>(AccessibilityBridge.java:352)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(FlutterView.java:912)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:303)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:520)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:414)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Stacktrace 3:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo;->mChildNodeIds:Landroid/util/LongArray;
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:471)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:429)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:70)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.<init>(AccessibilityBridge.java:352)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(FlutterView.java:912)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:303)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:520)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:414)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Stacktrace 4:

```
StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.NonSdkApiUsedViolation: Landroid/view/accessibility/AccessibilityRecord;->getSourceNodeId()J
    at android.os.StrictMode.lambda$static$1(StrictMode.java:428)
    at android.os.-$$Lambda$StrictMode$lu9ekkHJ2HMz0jd3F8K8MnhenxQ.accept(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethodInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.getPublicMethodRecursive(Class.java:2075)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2063)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:451)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder$ReflectionAccessors.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:429)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityViewEmbedder.<init>(AccessibilityViewEmbedder.java:70)
    at io.flutter.view.AccessibilityBridge.<init>(AccessibilityBridge.java:352)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.attachToFlutterEngine(FlutterView.java:912)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onCreateView(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:303)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.createFlutterView(FlutterActivity.java:520)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:414)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7144)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7135)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2931)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```